# dimension of tf.Variables change after some epochs

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, matrix-multiplication

I am new to TensorFlow and I am learning. 
I define some variables and start training. Everything runs smoothly for the first epochs but suddenly it throws the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [17952,50], In[1]: [0,20]
         [[{{node gradients/Embeddings_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1}}]]  
         [[gradients/Embeddings_1/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency/_1867]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [17952,50], In[1]: [0,20]
         [[{{node gradients/Embeddings_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1}}]]
```

My problem is that why it is giving the error after some epochs and not in the first place. Usually, these types of errors are thrown when the graph is built.

This is my code for creating the variables and embedding the trees:

```
    def __init__(self, vocab, embedding):

        self.add_model_variables()            

        with tf.variable_scope("Embeddings", reuse=True):
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                w_embed = tf.get_variable('WE', [self.vocab_embedding_size, self.embed_size])
                b_embed = tf.get_variable('bE', [1, self.embed_size])
                embeddings = tf.get_variable('embeddings')                                                                                                                                                       
                self.embeddings =  tf.add(tf.matmul(embeddings, w_embed), b_embed)


    def add_model_variables(self):
        myinitilizer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-self.calc_wt_init(),self.calc_wt_init())

        with tf.variable_scope('Embeddings'):
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                w_embed = tf.get_variable('WE', [self.vocab_embedding_size, self.embed_size], initializer = myinitilizer)
                b_embed = tf.get_variable('bE', [1, self.embed_size], initializer = myinitilizer)
                embeddings = tf.get_variable('embeddings', 
                                             initializer=tf.convert_to_tensor(self.pretrained_embedding),
                                             dtype=tf.float32)


        with tf.variable_scope('Composition'):
            self.W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', [2 * self.embed_size, self.embed_size], initializer = myinitilizer)
            self.b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', [1, self.embed_size], initializer = myinitilizer)

        with tf.variable_scope('Projection'):
            self.U = tf.get_variable('U', [self.embed_size, 1], initializer = myinitilizer)
            self.bu = tf.get_variable('bu', [self.max_number_nodes, 1], initializer = myinitilizer)


    def embed_tree(self, batch_index):
        def combine_children( left_tensor, right_tensor):
            return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.concat([left_tensor, right_tensor], axis=1, name='combine_children'), self.W1) + self.b1)

        def embed_word(word_index):
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                return tf.expand_dims(tf.gather(self.embeddings, word_index), 0)

        def loop_body(node_tensors, i):
            node_is_leaf = tf.gather(is_leaf, i)
            word = tf.gather(words, i)
            left_child = tf.gather(left_children, i)
            right_child = tf.gather(right_children, i)
            node_tensor = tf.cond(
                                node_is_leaf,
                                lambda: embed_word(word),
                                lambda: combine_children(
                                    node_tensors.read(n-right_child),
                                    node_tensors.read(n-left_child)))
            node_tensors = node_tensors.write(i, node_tensor)
            i = tf.add(i, 1)
            return node_tensors, i

        is_leaf = tf.gather(self.batch_is_leaf, batch_index)
        left_children = tf.gather(self.batch_left_children,  batch_index)
        right_children = tf.gather(self.batch_right_children, batch_index)
        words = tf.gather(self.batch_words, batch_index)
        n = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.not_equal(left_children, -1), tf.int32))-2
        #iself.batch_operation = tf.print(batch_index,'N::::::::',output_stream=sys.stdout)

        node_tensors = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=self.max_number_nodes,
                                      dynamic_size=False, clear_after_read=False, element_shape=[1, self.embed_size])
        loop_cond = lambda node_tensors, i: tf.less(i, n+2)  
        #with tf.control_dependencies([self.batch_operation]):
        node_tensors, _ = tf.while_loop(loop_cond, loop_body, [node_tensors, 0], parallel_iterations=1)
        tree_embedding = tf.convert_to_tensor(node_tensors.stack())
        return tree_embedding
```

The other problem is that I cannot replicate the error as it happens occasionally.

**Update:**

When I reduce the batch_size, the chance of getting this error reduces.
Is it possible for this to be because of working close to GPU memory limit?

Answer (score 1):

The tf.gather produces zeros for invalid indices on GPU (it works correctly on CPU however). In other words, Tensorflow does not check for the range of indices while running on GPU.

The errors caused by returned 0s accumulate on the gradient and finally result in confusing error messages that are not related to the original problem.

For reference:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3638

I changed tf.gather to index-based retrieval(a[i]) and the problem is fixed. I don't know exactly why!